# AngularJS weird flow

Tags: angularjs, control-flow

I've 2 functions in the scope f1 and f2, and I call f2 in the middle of f1.I can't get why f2 is called at the end of f1.(f2 edits the view).
For example, with

```
.....
$scope.f1 = function() {
   console.log("A");
   $scope.f2();
   console.log("C");
}

$scope.f2 = function() {
   console.log("B");
}
```

I get the output
    A
    C
    B

Why the procedural flow is not followed?In the real code, f2 manages the view.

Comment: Is something asynchronous (like an API call) happening in `f2`?

Comment: You have probably oversimplified the code because what is shown would not produce that result

Comment: No, no ajax or asynchronous stuff is in the two functions ,just scope variables editing  and dom manipulation.

Comment: Are you using setTimeout by any chance? this seems to be working, see below posted answer.

Comment: You should share more code on what kind of changes you're doing in both the functions.

Comment: Let's say that f2 manages asynchronous code, what should I do to force the code to run in a procedural way?

Comment: I'm using not setTimeout

Comment: Please provide the actual code. The one currently provided will not produce the described output.

Comment: OK I'll post the code, but even if copy directly the f2 code in  f1 the problem persists

Comment: The code is too wide, what it would be the right way  to wait for f2 and then continue with f1?

Answer (score 1):

[image]This seems to be working fine for me. See below JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/gzvnsth0/4/

See attached screenshot below.

```
function TestController($scope) {

  $scope.func1 = function(){
    console.log('A');
    $scope.func2();
    console.log('C');
  }

  $scope.func2 = function() {
   console.log('B');
  }
  $scope.func1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code produces A B C as expected.

```js
$scope = {}
$scope.f1 = function() {
   console.log("A");
   $scope.f2();
   console.log("C");
}

$scope.f2 = function() {
   console.log("B");
}
$scope.f1();  //A B C
```